# What kind of phrase? ...while walking down the stairs

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is walking a gerund in this sentence? I think while is acting as a conjunction. . .

Gloria tripped and fell while walking down the street.

Comment: Yes, *while* is a conjunction that means ["at the same time that something is happening"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/while). However, *walking* is not a gerund in this example. Here's a good description of gerunds: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/what-is-a-gerund

Answer (score 3):

*Walking* is a participle in your example. *While* is a subordinating conjunction.

> Gloria tripped and fell *while [she was] walking down the street.*

This is an **elliptical** adverbial clause of time: with certain conjunctions, subject pronouns and finite forms of *be* can be left out, as here. It is only possible if the subject is the same as that of the main clause.

> Happy, *though [she was] crying,* she accepted the prize.
>
> *While [she was] on the floor,* she remained unnoticed by her adversary.
>
> She could be ruthless *when offended*.

This origin of this ellipsis may have been influences by appositional phrases:

> *Displeased with her lover,* Cleopatra shut her bedroom door. — *(adjectival apposition*)
>
> Cleopatra, *a fairly competent ruler*, failed to expand the power of Egypt and died delivering her country to the Romans. — *(nominal apposition)*

A few others conjunctions can also be used without a finite verb, but in a different and more limited way:

> He was perceived as lacking vigour
>
> Queen Cleopatra, if passionate, still displayed great cunning and tact when necessary.
>
> He was beaten until dead/?crying.
>
> The floor was cleaned where dirty.

In certain limited cases, relative and interrogative pronouns can also have constructions that can be interpreted as ellipsis:

> The street [that one is] to take is on the left. — *(least clearly ellipsical)*
>
> Who [is one] to blame for this incident?
>
> Why [would you] cry if you can laugh?

Comment: English _never_ makes total sense (though Cerberus' answer does). Why doesn't _as_ behave like the synonymous _while_ ? Gloria tripped and fell as she was walking down the street. *Gloria tripped and fell as walking down the street.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, I never understood why *while* and *though* are like that. And *as* would have been a good candidate, also because  *as* can take a bare participle in other constructions: *she was perceived as lacking vigour*. But no! I suppose it is more or less possible with *if* where it means *though* (some style books will disapprove): *Queen Cleopatra, if passionate, still displayed great cunning and tact when necessary.* Then there is *he was beaten until dead/?crying*, which is also somewhat different and more limited. *He used to giggle when making love* qualifies, though.

Comment: @Cerberus: Qualifies as being [oh look, as + participle] very bad for his sex life, most likely!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Haha, right, no giggling. I've already added an *as* example to my answer.